# How to web scrape youtube transcripts with Beautifulsoup4 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my current code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Maybe I am not digging deep enough in the html and giving Beautifulsoup the right tags? At the moment, my code is returning me blanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_zrHZdhaBU")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
nameList = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "cp-2"})
for name in nameList:
    print(name.get_text())
```

Here is the code that I inspected. I'm trying to get Python to return back to me "but it was untucked"

```
<div id="cp-2" class="caption-line" data-time="7.54"><div class="caption-line-time">0:07</div><div class="caption-line-text">but it was untucked.</div></div>
```

***Edit

The code can be found by clicking on "more" next to the share button. Then you click on transcripts and you will see all the text there.

Comment: I can't find this line on the page and in the html. What is this line?

Comment: Are you sure this is not loaded dynamically via ajax? Open page source, there may not be such an element in static source.

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych
If you go to the youtube page, there is a "more" button next to share. Click on it, then click on transcripts. It is line 0:07.

Comment: @Andrey Moiseev
Maybe it is? I just noticed I do not see in open page source too. I just used google chrome's inspect to find the snippet. I'm looking at the transcript which can be found be clicking on "more" next to the share button.

Comment: @BHok You can probably find the file that the transcripts are loaded from. "Resources" or "Network" element inspector tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yes, it's loaded via Ajax: open the page, then open `Network` tab, sort requests by start time (latest requests first), click CC button on Youtube.

You get `api/timedtext` request, the response is an XML.
Here it the full url to the transcript:

https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?signature=1A03D323CBD455E9993B7AC447CA64764FA6FE75.59F4BD2D45A32E89FBF54B418EE2F763283A1007&asr_langs=fr%2Cja%2Cnl%2Ces%2Cru%2Cko%2Cit%2Cde%2Cpt%2Cen&key=yttt1&caps=asr&v=5_zrHZdhaBU&hl=en_US&expire=1480702409&sparams=asr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cv%2Cexpire&lang=en&fmt=srv3

I have no idea how this URL is generated, though. This requires invesigation of complex YouTube scripts, etc.

**EDIT:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30601863/633969) helped me. You can omit most of these parameters and just use this URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?&v=5_zrHZdhaBU&lang=en
```

Or this in general:

```
https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?&v={video_id}&lang={language_code}
```

Comment: Does this mean the transcript can only be scraped by going to another url? And cannot be scraped directly from the page?

Comment: @BHok Yes, you need a different url. You need to extract the `{video_id}` part of your old url, for example, with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/RuGXmI/2): `v=(?P<video_id>[a-zA-Z\d_]+)`. Or parse the url with some library and get the `v` parameter, it's a tedious task. And then put into the new one, if you need this to be done automatically.

Comment: @BHok If this answer solves your problem, consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green check).