# Download YouTube subtitles using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, youtube

I have the following code that download xml file with the subtitle of a video from YouTube

```
Sub Test()
Dim http        As Object
Dim oStream     As Object

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=qANA6POtuFo", False
http.send
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Write http.responseBody

oStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.xml", 2
oStream.Close
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work for other videos 
for example I tried this link
v=4Z3EJrh7_5k

Any idea how to do the download with any video with a subtitle?

Comment: I noticed that 4 votes to close this question. Is there a specific reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I researched, you cannot download from `4Z3EJrh7_5k` because it's subtitle is not a file someone uploaded, but it is generated automatically.

To see if a video has any subtitle file, you can use `http://video.google.com/timedtext?type=list&v=qANA6POtuFo`, and it will list every file with languages inserted in the video. You can note that it shows only one, even if you go to the video and click, there are two (English and English (Automatically generated))

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. So there is no way to do that using VBA ... Any other way

Comment: It looks like there is no file for it to download, since it is generated automatically. It will only work if its a submitted subtitle.

Comment: If you may, check http://titaniumhelp.fullerton.edu/m/FAQ/l/498105-how-do-i-export-the-youtube-auto-generated-captions, but it is a more manual approach

Comment: Also, this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013431/extract-automatic-captions-from-youtube-video . It seems inconsistent whether you can or not download the automatic. But a way to check is to use the list I mentioned on my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable replies. Hope one day I could develop a code using VBA to do such task

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. These are the information I got about your problem.

Comment: No sorry. You do well. Thank you very much